# How to echo statements between two times of day in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to display a message depending on the time of day between four specific times, and I don't understand my error. Below is my code and my error message.

```
$curtime = date("h:i:sa");
echo $curtime;
if ($curtime >= 5:45:00am and $curtime =< 11:59:59am){
    echo "Good Morning";
}
if ($curtime >= 12:00:00pm and $curtime =< 5:59:59pm){
    echo "Good Afternoon";
}
if ($curtime >= 6:00:00pm and $curtime =< 5:44:59am){
    echo "Good Evening";
}
```

Error message:

```
PHP Syntax Check: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ':' in your code on line 11
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is from the `5:45:00am` text just hanging out there.

You need to create a date object from a string, eg:

```
$curtime = date_create_from_format("h:i:sa", date("h:i:sa"));
$date1 = date_create_from_format("h:i:sa", '5:45:00am');
$date2 = date_create_from_format("h:i:sa", '11:59:59am');
```

And then use that date object to compare against the current:

```
if ($curtime >= $date1 and $curtime <= $date2){
    echo "Good Morning";
}
```

However, it would be faster to just store the current 24 hour + minutes + seconds in a variable and just use those for comparison

```
$curtime = date('His');


if ($curtime >= 54500 and $curtime <= 0){
    echo "Good Morning";
}
if ($curtime >= 120000 and $curtime <= 175959){
    echo "Good Afternoon";
}
if ($curtime >= 180000 and $curtime <= 54459am){
    echo "Good Evening";
}
```

Comment: Hi Drew, thanks for your response. I think I made the changes you suggested, but I am still getting errors.    Error: There are 3 control structures that contain a single equal sign '=' instead of != !==, ==, or ===:
if ($curtime >= $start1 and $curtime =< $end1){
if ($curtime >= $start2 and $curtime =< $end2){
if ($curtime >= $start3 and $curtime =< $end3){
PHP Syntax Check: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<' in your code on line 22
if ($curtime >= $start1 and $curtime =< $end1){. Any ideas?

Comment: typo: change `=<` to `<=`

Comment: Can you edit your post and show us what your code looks like after your edits?

Comment: You solved my problem many thanks!

Comment: Glad I could help, can you mark my answer as accepted.